# Wordpress - query first and name from custom post type

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I want to query first and last name using custom post type metaboxes.

Code i am using:

```
$name = 'John Doe';

$args = array( 
    'post_type'     => 'customers',
    'post_status'   => array( 'publish', 'pending', 'draft' ),
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'orderby'       => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key'      => 'customer_first_name'
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'           => 'customer_first_name',
            'value'         => $name,
            'compare'       => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'           => 'customer_last_name',
            'value'         => $name,
            'compare'       => 'LIKE',
        ),      
    ),  
);  

$customers = get_posts($args);

$num = count( $customers );
```

If i search only "John" results are showing up. If i search full name "John Doe" there are no results. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's show no result because you don't split the name first name and last name.

```
$name = 'John Doe';
$parts = explode(" ", $name);
$first_name = $parts[0];
$last_name = (count($name) > 1) ? $name[count($name)-1]: $first_name;
$args = array( 
    'post_type'     => 'customers',
    'post_status'   => array( 'publish', 'pending', 'draft' ),
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'orderby'       => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key'      => 'customer_first_name',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'           => 'customer_first_name',
            'value'         => $first_name,
            'compare'       => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'           => 'customer_last_name',
            'value'         => $last_name,
            'compare'       => 'LIKE',
        ),      
    ),  
);  

$customers = get_posts($args);

$num = count( $customers );
```

Like international name, if last name is blank then last name will use first name too.